# Interceptor and global exception handling

Tags: spring-boot, exception, interceptor

I have a post-interceptor. When the control layer is executed and returns information, the post-interceptor will be executed. At this time, an exception in the post-interceptor will be caught by the global exception handling and a prompt message will be returned. Use "postman" to test and control The information of layer and global exception handling is returned at the same time. Is this really returned? I wrote a test example. In the same situation, only the information of the control layer is returned. I think it should return the information of global exception handling.

Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/book")
@Validated
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public R searchBook(@RequestParam(value = "q", required = false, defaultValue = "") String q) {
        return R.select(bookService.getBookByKeyword(q));
    }
}
```

Interceptor

```java
public class LogInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public LogInterceptor(LoggerResolver loggerResolver) {
        this.loggerResolver = loggerResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        // There will be a runtime exception here
    }
}
```

Global Exception Handing

```java
@Order
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * Exception
     */
    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public R processException(Exception exception) {
        log.error("", exception);
        return R.error();
    }
}
```

Result

```json
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        // ...
    ],
    "type": "success",
    "message": "OK"
}{
    "code": 500,
    "type": "error",
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

"R extends HashMap<String, Object>", used to unify the return structure.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code snippet, I'm not sure what are those R in the searchBook and processException

try this (edit the processException to meet your specs):

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<?> searchBook(@RequestParam(value = "q", required = false, defaultValue = "") String q) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.getBookByKeyword(q), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
public ResponseEntity<?> processException(Exception exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorDTO(exception.getMessage()), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

Comment: "R extends HashMap<String, Object>", used to unify the return structure.